# How to send ampdu using scapy

Tags: python, scapy

I hope to use scapy in python to customize sending A-MPDU.

My reference code comes from https://github.com/rpp0/aggr-inject/blob/master/packets.py.

```py
class AMPDUPacket():
    def __init__(self, recv_mac, src_mac, dst_mac, ds=0x01):
        self.rt = RadioTap(len=18, present='Flags+Rate+Channel+dBm_AntSignal+Antenna', notdecoded='\x00\x6c' + get_frequency(CHANNEL) + '\xc0\x00\xc0\x01\x00\x00')
        self.dot11hdr = Dot11(type="Data", subtype=DOT11_SUBTYPE_QOS_DATA, addr1=recv_mac, addr2=src_mac, addr3=dst_mac, SC=0x3060, FCfield=ds) / Raw("\x00\x00")
        self.data = self.rt
        self.num_subframes = 0
        self.recv_mac = recv_mac
        self.src_mac = src_mac
        self.dst_mac = dst_mac

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data[RadioTap].payload)

    # Higher layer packet
    def add_msdu(self, msdu, msdu_len=-1):
        # Default msdu len
        if msdu_len == -1:
            msdu_len = len(msdu)

        mpdu_len = msdu_len + len(self.dot11hdr) + 4  # msdu + mac80211 + FCS

        if mpdu_len % 4 != 0:
            padding = "\x00" * (4 - (mpdu_len % 4))  # Align to 4 octets
        else:
            padding = ""
        mpdu_len <<= 4
        crc_fun = crcmod.mkCrcFun(0b100000111, rev=True, initCrc=0x00, xorOut=0xFF)

        crc = crc_fun(struct.pack('<H', mpdu_len))
        maccrc = dot11crc(str(self.dot11hdr / msdu))
        delim_sig = 0x4E

        #print('a-mpdu: len %d crc %02x delim %02x' % (mpdu_len >> 4, crc, delim_sig))
        #hexdump(maccrc)
        ampdu_header = struct.pack('<HBB', mpdu_len, crc, delim_sig)
        #hexdump(ampdu_header)

        self.data = self.data / ampdu_header / self.dot11hdr / msdu / maccrc / padding

        self.num_subframes += 1

    def add_padding(self, times):  # Add padding delimiter
        for i in range(0, times):
            self.data /= "\x00\x00\x20\x4e"

    def add_padding_bogus(self, times):  # Add bogus padding
        for i in range(0, times):
            self.data /= "\xff\xff\xff\xff"

    def send(self):
        return sendp(self.data, iface=MONITOR_INTERFACE, verbose=False)

    def dump_to_file(self):
        with open('ampdu.bin', 'w') as f:
            for i in range(0, 1024):
                f.write(str(self))  # Try to shift position so our payload will land on correct offset
```

My main.py:

```py
ampdu_pkt = AMPDUPacket(DEFAULT_SOURCE_MAC, DEFAULT_DEST_MAC, DEFAULT_DEST_MAC, 0x03)
ampdu_pkt.add_msdu(ping_packet(count,DEFAULT_SOURCE_IP ,DEFAULT_DEST_IP))
ampdu_pkt.add_msdu(ping_packet(count,DEFAULT_SOURCE_IP ,DEFAULT_DEST_IP))
ampdu_pkt.add_msdu(ping_packet(count,DEFAULT_SOURCE_IP ,DEFAULT_DEST_IP))
ampdu_pkt.add_padding(8)
ampdu_pkt.send()
```

When using wireshark to capture the packet, I found that the info of the data packet is
Ethernet II, at the same time, the parsing of src_mac and dst_mac is wrong.
I don't know where the problem lies. Is it because scapy cannot send ampdu, or is my ampdu package constructed incorrectly? Hope to get everyone's help.